# Grub problems with Linux Mint and Windows 8.1 dual boot

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, bootloader

I've been trying to make a dual boot configuration with Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca and Windows 8.1.

These are the steps I followed in installing this setup:

1. Install Windows 8.
2. Run all available updates.
3. Update to Windows 8.1.
4. Install Linux Mint (logical partition for `/`, `/home` and swap)
5. Run into problems with grub.

When I try installing the bootloader on my primary SSD (`/dev/sda`) I run into a non working GRUB (after BIOS screen only a black screen).
When on the other hand I install the bootloader on my secondary HDD (`/dev/sdb`) and change boot priority to HDD in the BIOS I get to the GRUB bootloader.

From `/dev/sdb` I am able to boot Linux Mint without problems, when I choose any of the 3 (3 Windows 8 loaders?) Windows loaders I run into a black screen again.

So I restored the default Windows bootloader, and I am now able to boot into Linux Mint with HDD as boot priority in BIOS and boot into Windows with the SSD as boot priority in my BIOS, but I cannot seem to get both working via the GRUB bootloader.

This is what I tried to do to fix it so far. At first I was trying to fix the issues with GRUB not showing on my SSD.

1. Reinstall and update GRUB bootloader via this [method](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd).
2. Moving my Windows 1GB from the beginning of the SSD space and making a `/boot` partition to counter [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1030887).
3. Reinstalling Linux Mint several times.
4. Installing Ubuntu (same issue)

Then I discovered that on `/dev/sdb` the Grub bootloader seemed to work, so I changed boot priority to my HDD and tried to fix the Windows not loading bug.

1. Reinstalling GRUB
2. Updating GRUB (which still gave me 3 bootoptions for Windows 8.1 which I find strange)
3. Installing Grub Customizer on Linux Mint and adding a Windows 8.1 boot option manually

Unfortunately none of the above solved my problems, I am running both Windows and Linux Mint in Legacy Mode (so no UEFI or EFI issues). My SSD may has a GPT partition format, although I am not completely sure of this. I installed Windows 8.1 before Linux Mint so whatever Windows 8.1 uses as partition method I have.

**Hardware Specifications:**

- Crucial M4 256GB mSATA SSD
- Ordinary 500GB HDD
- All in the Lenovo Y500 (i5 edition) laptop

Comment: An easy next step might be to try the free GRUB Boot Repair Disk (https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/).  It's pretty effective at solving a lot of GRUB issues.

Comment: Just tried, no useful result.

Comment: Looks like you need a bigger hammer.  :-)